# How to control the execution of getIntent() in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this login activity which is also the launching activity.
I wanted to send some error messages from other activities to this login activity through intents. I used this piece of code for accepting the message,

> Intent i = getIntent();
>   String Message = i.getExtras().getString("msg");

Since during the initial launch no value is passed to getIntent(), adding this piece of code will crash my app.

How to I implement this logic ?

Comment: `String Message =  i.getStringExtra("msg");`

Comment: Try i.getStringExtra("msg")

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya My issue is such that I actually want that piece of code written above to execute. But I do not want it to execute whenever login activity is called **without** an intent value.

Comment: Don't name your variables with capital letters. That is reserved for classes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check for null values in `getIntent()` like this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if(i.getExtras() != null) {
    String Message = i.getExtras().getString("msg");
}
```

Comment: Gimme 4 more minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if (i != null && i.hasExtra("msg")) {
String Message = i.getStringExtra("msg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if (i != null){
    String Message = i.getStringExtra("msg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this

```
String msg = "";
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    msg= getIntent().getStringExtra("msg");
}
```